# View's in Entity Framework won't update

Tags: entity-framework, view

I have a view which includes data from multiple tables.

When I call that view, the results are loaded into the memory and stored. After I make some changes to the other tables which should effect the view, the view don't know anything about the changes.

So when I call that view again, for example a Get() method, EF returns the values of the stored data.

Of course I want the updated data. How can I force the view to get the data from DB and not from memory? Or is there a better strategy?

Better if I can make the view aware of the changes being made. Is this achievable with entity configuration, maybe by using HasRequired() method to map FK's?

**EDIT:** 
I am using repository and unit of work pattern. So I am not creating and disposing a new context each time. Please consider this.

Comment: Are you using EF in combination with WCF? What kind of application do you have?

Comment: No, it is a WPF application. I debugged the code, so I know the actual data returned from the EF.

Comment: But are you talking to dbcontext directly?

Comment: @Sander Pham, Nop, see my edit please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you execute the Linq query on the view use `AsNoTracking()` extension method. This will force EF to always use data from database instead of memory:

```
var result = from x in context.ViewSet.AsNoTracking()
             select x;
```

EF will not handle any automatic data refresh for you.